# python most similar prefix from redis

Tags: python, redis

I have all countries telephone prefixes lists in my redis, when a customer call a number, i need to find most similar exact prefixes for this numbers in my redis.

```
redis example keys: 
auth:prefix:49
auth:prefix:49115
auth:prefix:49116
auth:prefix:4915
auth:prefix:491511
auth:prefix:491512
auth:prefix:491514
auth:prefix:491515
auth:prefix:491516
```

example number matches:

```
4911234XXXXXXXX -> auth:prefix:49
491514XXXXXXXXX -> auth:prefix:491514
491513XXXXXXXXX -> auth:prefix:4915
491515XXXXXXXXX -> auth:prefix:491515
```

I tried deleting numbers from the right side one by one and i check every step, it work but it's not efficent at all. Can anyone suggest a more efficient method?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MGET` to get all possible prefix of your input in one call to Redis. The longest key with non-nil value is your most similar prefix:

Say your input is *49151498*, all possible prefix is: *4, 49, 491, 4915, 49151, 491514, 4915149, 49151498*:

```
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> mget 4 49 491 4915 49151 491514 4915149 49151498
1) (nil)
2) "0"
3) (nil)
4) "0"
5) (nil)
6) "0"
7) (nil)
8) (nil)
```

The longest key with non-nil value is the 6th prefix: *491514*.

With this solution, you only need to call Redis once, and do some check on client side. It should be much faster than the original solution, i.e. multiple calls to Redis.

Comment: this approach worked for me thanks